# Интерфейс Iterable

Tags: java

Есть код класса IterNap:

```
public class IterNap implements Iterable {

    ArrayList <Character> list;

    public IterNap(String s) { 
            for(int i=0; i<s.length();i++) {
                this.list.add(s.charAt(i));
            }
    } 



    public Iterator <Character> iterator() {

        return list.iterator();
    }   
}
```

В следующем классе в строке `for (char z: nap)` выбивает ошибку:

```
 public static void main(String [] args) {
            IterNap nap = new IterNap("OneTwoOne");

            for (char z: nap) 
                System.out.print(z + " ");
        }
      }
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: У Вас list не инициализирован отсюда и ошибка

Comment: Нужно указать информацию о возникшем исключении (сообщение и тип) в самом тексте вопроса.

Answer (score 3):

Интерфейс `Iterable<T>` является параметризованным, как видно из названия, но Вы явно не указываете, что тип `T=Character`. Из-за этого, вы не можете написать

```
for (char z: nap) 
            System.out.print(z + " ");
```

так как компилятор считает, что Ваш `nap` заполнен элементами типа `Object`.